# Setting a variable before it is called - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a store which utilises JCrop

Now the aspect ratio set by jcrop will change depending on what they answered for Question 2 as the dimensions of the canvas will need to change.

You can see this in action by uploading a photo under question 4. The problem that I have is that this works perfectly well if I change question 2 AFTER I have uploaded an image and initialised JCrop. However, the first time it is initialised it will use a squared aspect ratio (1) which is the default setting of JCrop.

How can I get it to use the aspect ratio set by Question 2 by default?

```
    $('select[name=size]').click(function() {
    getPrice();
    });

$('select[name=size]').change(function () {
    getPrice($(this).val());
});
//custom function to change aspect ratio depending on answer on question 2
function getPrice(aspectRatioStr) {
    var parts = aspectRatioStr.split('x'),
        num = parseInt(parts[0]),
        denom = parseInt(parts[1]),
        newAspectRatio = num / denom;
    if (!jcrop_api) return;
    jcrop_api.setOptions({
        aspectRatio: newAspectRatio
    });
    jcrop_api.focus();
}

            // standard jcrop initialization
            $('#preview').Jcrop({
                minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
                aspectRatio : 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                onChange: updateInfo,
                onSelect: updateInfo,
                onRelease: clearInfo,
                boxWidth: 765
            }, function(){

                // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                var bounds = this.getBounds();
                boundx = bounds[0];
                boundy = bounds[1];

                // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                jcrop_api = this;

            getPrice($('#name').val());
            });
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
getPrice($('#name').val());
```

Replace it with:

```
getPrice($('select[name=size]').val());
```

Comment: Hi Sahbeewah! Thank you very much for taking the time to look over my code, your suggestion was exactly the problem! Thanks again :)